# How to redirect url (httpd)

Tags: linux, apache, redhat

In my Apache server I need to redirect my URL `http://10.11.10.11:9003/ObiController` to http://abc.co.in.

How do I redirect to accomplish this ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For redirecting in apache with port, you can add the below line to you httpd.conf file

```
Redirect 301 /ObiController http://abc.co.in:9003
```

A 301 redirect refers to the HTTP status code that is returned when a HTTP request for a specific resourse is redirected.

Answer (score 0):

Easier method is to add the following line in your .htaccess file located under your document root folder. This uses regular expression and checks for "ObiController" word only.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^ObiController$ http://abc.co.in
```